# What is the matrix diagonalization precision in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, precision

I don't know what kind of algorithm it runs in the background but it seems that it cannot handle matrices which contain elements on the order of 10^-5.

Comment: Can you give a precise example.

Answer (score 1):

It can handle upto 16 digits. Type:

```
format long;
a = 1.234567890123456;
```

in your MATLAB code or command window.

4 decimal places is the limit of format short.